# jQuery function with loop won't work

Tags: jquery

I tried to make a simple function which should give me some alerts in the window. I have made an mistake there but cannot find it. Here my code:

```js
var testList = new Array {
  "This",
  "is",
  "a",
  "loop"
};

function printList(list) {
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    alert(list[i]);
  }
  return;
}

$("#button1").click(printList(list));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click me!" />
```

Comment: `$("#button1").click(printList(list));` => `$("#button1").click(printList(testlist));`

Comment: new Array { "This", "is", "a", "loop" }; this is an invalid array you will get a error on this line. Change it to "new Array ( "This", "is", "a", "loop" );"

Comment: Thanks but still don't work :(

Comment: Just for future reference you can see the problem when you open the console (press F12). The error is listed there. You can also see it in the snippet I edited in to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several issues:

- You need to use `()` to enclose the array items, not `{}`.
- The variable is `testList`, not just `list`.
- You're executing the `printList()` function on load of the page as you're passing the *result* of the function, not its *reference*.
- The `return` is redundant when placed at the end of a function

Also note that you should really use `console.log` for debugging, not `alert()`. The latter is bad as it coerces data types, so what you see may not necessarily be the actual value. It's also modal, which means it blocks the UI updating. Not to mention it's really annoying when you do it in a loop and you have to click 'Ok' N times.

Finally, you can shorten the array definition by using just `[]` to declare the elements, like this:

```js
var testList = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'loop'];

function printList(list) {
  for (i = 0; i < testList.length; i++) {
    console.log(testList[i]);
  }
}

$("#button1").click(function() {
  printList(testList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click me!" />
```

Comment: Yes but I want to make some alerts. Why do I get alerts when I haven't yet clicked the button?

Comment: That's addressed in the third bullet point - you're calling the function immediately

Comment: How can I make a reference to it?

Comment: You provide a function to the `click()` method - it's all in the working code example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var testList = ["This", "is", "a", "loop"];

 

$("#button1").click(function(){
printList(testList);
});

    function printList(list) {
      for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        alert(list[i]);
      }
      return;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click me!" />
```

Comment: The point of this website is to educate people. Dumping code with 'Try this' helps no one - not least when it's identical to a more complete answer that was already given.

Answer (score 0):

```
Creating an Array in Javascript
Syntax:
var array_name = [item1, item2, ...];
var testList = ["This", "is", "a", "loop" ];

JavaScript HTML DOM EventListener:
The addEventListener() method attaches an event handler to the specified element.
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){ printList(testList); });
```